# How can I replace a value based on an element name in my XML file using sed, awk or ideally xmlstartlet

Tags: bash, awk, sed, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to replace the value 10 with the value 5 where testname="TG1"

Change This:

```
<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">10</stringProp>
```

To This:

```
 <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">5</stringProp>
```

Snippet Example

Before:

```
<ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="TG1" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
    </elementProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">10</stringProp>
  </ThreadGroup>
<ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="TG2" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
    </elementProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">50</stringProp>
  </ThreadGroup>
```

After:

```
<ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="TG1" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
    </elementProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">5</stringProp>
  </ThreadGroup>
<ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="TG2" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
    </elementProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">50</stringProp>
  </ThreadGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you actually have valid XML, this is really an xpath problem:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
    --update '//ThreadGroup[@testname="TG1"]//stringProp[@name="ThreadGroup.num_threads"]' \
    --value 5 \
    file.xml
```

To save the file in place, change `ed` to `ed --inplace`

Answer (score 0):

Try this awk-command:

```
awk '$0 ~ "testclass=\"ThreadGroup\"" && $0 ~ "testname=\"TG1\""{replace=1}
     $0 ~ "testclass=\"ThreadGroup\"" && $0 !~ "testname=\"TG1\""{replace=0}
     replace{gsub("name=\"ThreadGroup.num_threads\">10</stringProp>",
                  "name=\"ThreadGroup.num_threads\">5</stringProp>",$0)}1' in.txt
```

It will replace all `name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">10</stringProp>` by `name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">5</stringProp>` if they are within `<... testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="TG1" ...>`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/10<\/stringProp>/,"5</stringProp>")}1' file

<ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="TG1" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
    </elementProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">5</stringProp>
  </ThreadGroup>
<ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="TG2" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
    </elementProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">50</stringProp>
  </ThreadGroup>
```